# Backyard Greenhouse Studio Sink Drainage Question

Tags: plumbing, code-compliance, sewer, backyard, drains

I live in San Francisco and have a permit to build a greenhouse ceramics studio in my backyard. I am a potter. I am currently renovating my 1915 house and adding the studio as part of the plan.

I want to have a sink in the studio but am told by contractor I have to run a completely new sanitary line to the street, not use the current sewer drain already in the patio. NOTE: SF does not have separate sewer and sanitary lines but perhaps this is a new requirement. That would involve demolition of the cement stairs (backyard is above basement level) or a trench inside the house for the drain pipe. Do not want to demolish anymore than I already have had to.

QUESTION: The greenhouse is very close to a patio runoff drain. The patio will be demolished and a new cement pad poured. I am planning to put in french drains using Hydroblox to absorb runoff back into ground instead of going to sewer.

OPTION 1:  I am wondering if I can convert the current sanitary line by tying my sink to it and not allowing runoff from patio to go down it. There is a sewer drain at the bottom of the cement stairs leading to ground level for runoff from cement pad.

OPTION 2: Leave the patio drain as is, and make a dry well sink. Because clay should be kept out of drains, I will install a clay trap. No food waste will be allowed down this drain. It may be that SF does not like dry well sinks but I am not sure.

Is there any other option?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Local regulations override what we say, but a local plumber should be up to date on regulations better than a building contractor.  You do not mention if the contractor is a licensed plumber, or just a building contractor, who uses plumbers.

Comment: You will be washing clay down that drain. Eventually it will clog up the drain somewhere. It needs dedicated drain line.

Answer (score 1):

My wife is a potter. We put in a sediment trap under the sink. And we were allowed to connect to the main sewer line. We have a septic system.

The sediment trap may allow you to connect to the main line. Check with your local authority.

At our previous house, where we had 10 acres, we just let the water go to the garden, after a sediment trap.

Answer (score -1):

The drain pipes in basement do not need to go underground in SFO.

You can easily run a 2 inch drain pipe from patio sink true the basement, and connect to main drain at home exit to the street. No digging involved here.

Obviously it has to be properly sloped.

You might want to install a inline sump pump after the sink.

I live in SFO and that is how it is done in my home.